# JSON to a Java collection

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I got JSON like

```
{
"items":[
{
"id":15
,"name":"abc"
}
,{
"id":16
,"name":"xyz%"
}
,{
"id":17
,"name":"qwerty"
}
,{
"id":18
,"name":"rudloph"
}
,{
"id":19
,"name":"jane"
}
,{
"id":20
,"name":"doe"
}
]
}
```

I have class which is like:

```java
public class Foo {
    public String id;    
    public String name;
}
```

And I want to convert this JSON into `List<Foo>`. How can i do this? Right now I am doing like:

```java
List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<>();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray araray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
for(int i =0 ; i < araray.length();i++){
    Foo dto = new Foo();
    dto.setId(Long.valueOf((String) araray.getJSONObject(i).get("id")));
    dto.setName((String) araray.getJSONObject(i).get("name"));
    fooList.add(dto);
}
```

PS: Cannot change JSON. Jackson or Gson. Please let me know with code example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722587/how-do-i-convert-a-json-array-into-a-java-list-im-using-svenson

Comment: I can convert it using JSONOBjJECT and then iterating through JSONARRAY , but i was thinking if gson or jackson can convert this for me

Comment: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35920152/2310289)

Comment: Seriously, it's 1000 times easier to google it than write a new post here.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use the java json api and you need bind it manually

Comment: I am doing something like this  
List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<>();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray araray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
   for(int i =0 ; i < araray.length();i++){
     Foo dto = new Foo();
     dto.setId(Long.valueOf((String) araray.getJSONObject(i).get("id")));
     dto.setName((String) araray.getJSONObject(i).get("name"));
     fooList.add(dto);
   }

Is there any better way

Comment: you need to use jakson- jason api that work like jax b

Comment: in rest api  rest implementation it internally used jakson-son you no need to manage

Answer (score 0):

If you use gson, you may use `TypeToken` to load the json string into a custom `Foo` object.

```
List<Foo> objects = gson.fromJson(source, new TypeToken<List<Foo>>(){}.getType());
```

`source` can be `String` or `BufferedReader`.

Comment: tried that also got error
"Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $"

Answer (score 0):

You are having the wrong model for the JSON String. actually the list of `Foo` is inside another Model. Simply write another class like

```
public class Item {

    List<Foo> items;

    public Item() {
    }

   // getter setter
}
```

Now you can use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` like this

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Item item = mapper.readValue(json, Item.class);

for(Foo foo : item.getItems()) {
            ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with GSON.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, List<Foo>> objects = gson.fromJson(source,
    new TypeToken<Map<String, List<Foo>>>(){}.getType());
List<Foo> list = objects.get("items");
```

Comment: Thanks that worked :)