# How to convert JSON file to List

Tags: java, android, json, list

I am trying to turn a `JSON` where there is an array of objects for each object 4 properties: question, answer 1, answer 2, answer 3, correct answer.
I created a `Class` called Question.
I want to create an `array` / `list` of Question and then use it

The JSON is located in the assets folder named: `questions.json`

```
    public class Question{
    private String title;
    private String a1, a2, a3;
    private String cA;

    public Question(String title, String a1, String a2, String a3, String cA){
        this.title = title;
        this.a1 = a1;
        this.a2 = a2;
        this.a3 = a3;
        this.cA = cA;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getA1() {
        return a1;
    }

    public void setA1(String a1) {
        this.a1 = a1;
    }

    public String getA2() {
        return a2;
    }

    public void setA2(String a2) {
        this.a2 = a2;
    }

    public String getA3() {
        return a3;
    }

    public void setA3(String a3) {
        this.a3 = a3;
    }

    public String getcA() {
        return cA;
    }

    public void setcA(String cA) {
        this.cA = cA;
    }


}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a JSON array into a Java List. I'm using svenson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722587/how-do-i-convert-a-json-array-into-a-java-list-im-using-svenson)

Comment: Yeah but can you customize an answer to my object? I don't understand how to do that

Comment: This answer may be easier for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/10726030/3257579, if it isn't tell me

Comment: What should I write here> ArrayList list = parser.parse(ArrayList.class, json); ?
(json value)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below methods to read from a file and convert the JSON array to a List of Questions.

```
public String readJsonFromFile(String filePath) throws IOException, ParseException {
    String json = Files.readString(Paths.get("file path"));
    return new JSONParser().parse(json).toString();
}


public List<Question> convert(String JsonString) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        CollectionType typeReference =
                TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, Question.class);
        List<Question> questions =  om.readValue(JsonString, typeReference);
        return questions;
    }
```

If your JSON keys and Java class fields are different, use @JsonPropery annotation to map keys to fields

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Question {
    

    @JsonProperty("question")
    private String title;
    @JsonProperty("answer 1")
    private String a1;
    @JsonProperty("answer 2")
    private String a2;
    @JsonProperty("answer 3")
    private String a3;
    @JsonProperty("correct answer")
    private String cA;

    //setters & getters
}
```

> **Required Jars:**
> jackson-annotations.jar
> jackson-core.jar
> jackson-databind.jar
> json-simple.jar //used to parse Json file to
> String

Answer (score 0):

You have two steps

1. Get JSON string from the file, use [read file from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets)
2. Extract items from the JSON string use [How do I convert a JSON array into a Java List. I'm using svenson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722587/how-do-i-convert-a-json-array-into-a-java-list-im-using-svenson)

Comment: Sorry I don't get it can you please open a chat with me?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Class Questions.java which has a List of Question object and use the following to convert into a list.

```
public class Questions {

List<Question> questions;

//getter setter }




Questions questions = null;
    try {
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(
                "replace with path"));
        questions = new Gson().fromJson(reader, Questions.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Example json:

```
{
"questions": [
    {
        "title": "What is 1+2 ?",
        "a1": "1",
        "a2": "2",
        "a3": "3",
        "cA": "3"
    },
    {
        "title": "What is 2*3 ?",
        "a1": "6",
        "a2": "4",
        "a3": "3",
        "cA": "6"
    }
]}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
String json = Files.readString(Paths.get("path\of\your\json\file"));

Map<String,List<Example>> result1 = parser.parse(Map.class, json);
List<Question> list = new ArrayList<Value>(result1.values());
```

**1)** read your json file and put it in a string variable

**2)** deserialize your json in a map

**3)** convert your map to a list of Question

Comment: Sorry I don't get it can you please open a chat with me?

Comment: Sorry, but how can I open a chat with you? I don't know how to do it

Comment: I am in the room. You can get in (room name: Json to list)

Comment: send me a link here